# Can I undo a flag? Has this feature been added?

Tags: feature-request

I accidentally clicked the flag button while on mobile. I have done this twice now and it would be nice to be able to undo the flag within a 5 minute window or something if I accidentally clicked it. Just like I can edit comments within 5 minutes before it's locked in.

There has been discussion of this here:

[Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

And here

[Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)

What is the status on this issue? Some of these feature requests are quite old. Why hasn't it been added?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you're likely to get much good information by asking here. It'd be better to ask on [meta.SE], or resurrect one of the existing questions, or something like that.